# localhost Parser Error: Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, localhost

I have a webpage I created that deploys just fine on our server, but simply refuses to run under my local host.

The error is:

> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'AcpServiceNS.Default'.

[image: Parser Error]

As you can see from my HTML and code behind, this namespace and class both match up!

### Why does this give Parser Error?

[image: HTML Default]

[image: Codebehind Default]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"` to `CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"`.

Since you are saying that the project does not contain the project file or solution file, I think the problem is here. The IIS is not able to understand the project type.

Since you are used FTP to IIS, very that you are using the .NET 4.0 AppPool

Comment: **CodeFile**! That is awesome! I don't know why VS created that page using CodeBehind since there is no MasterPage. Thank You!

Comment: I still have to wait 4 more minutes before I can accept this answer, though. Dumb rule.

Comment: It's because, when VS deploy your project he compiles all codefiles into a dll so it remains only aspx pages